# Android Magento Soap PersistenceException in ElementList

Tags: java, android, magento, soap, simple-framework

I get the error

> Android Magento Soap Api org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Element 'result' is already used with @org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList

when I make request to fetch catalogProductMedia from Magento using Soap. Below are XML files and Classes.

### CatalogProductAttributeMediaListResponse.xml

```
<message name="catalogProductAttributeMediaListResponse">
<part name="result" type="typens:catalogProductImageEntityArray"/>
</message>
```

### CatalogProductAttributeMediaListResponse.java

```
    @Root(name = CatalogProductAttributeMediaListResponse.ROOT_NAME, strict = false)
public class CatalogProductAttributeMediaListResponse {

    public static final String ROOT_NAME = "n0:catalogProductAttributeMediaListResponse";

    @Element(required = false)
    @Path("Body/catalogProductAttributeMediaListResponse")
    private CatalogProductImageEntityArray result;
}
```

### CatalogProductImageEntityArray.xml

```
<complexType name="catalogProductImageEntityArray">
<complexContent>
<restriction base="soapenc:Array">
<attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="typens:catalogProductImageEntity[]"/>
</restriction>
</complexContent>
</complexType>
```

### CatalogProductImageEntityArray.java

```
@Root(name = "catalogProductImageEntityArray", strict = false)
public class CatalogProductImageEntityArray {
    @ElementList(inline = true, entry = "item", required = false)
    private List<CatalogProductImageEntity> productImageEntityList;
}
```

### CatalogProductImageEntity.xml

```
<complexType name="catalogProductImageEntity">
<all>
<element name="file" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="label" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="position" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="exclude" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="url" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="types" type="typens:ArrayOfString"/>
</all>
</complexType>
```

### CatalogProductImageEntity.java

```
@Root(name = "catalogProductEntity", strict = false)
public class CatalogProductImageEntity {
    @Element(required = false)
    private String url;
}
```

i just want to fetch url and i have already generated all the getter and setter methods. Help Me Please

Answer (score 1):

Try to annotate result like

```
@Element(required = false, inline=true)
@Path("Body/catalogProductAttributeMediaListResponse")
private CatalogProductImageEntityArray result;
```

Comment: Sorry, but there is no inline attribute in Element tag

Comment: Do you have any other idea ?

Comment: Sry man im lost, im sure here some issue with mapping of result
maybe Element should be changed to ElementList... sry

Comment: if i changed it to Element to ElmentList Then no error is there but also data is not mapped to the classes.